# JS/JQUERY складывать все теги li и сделать средняю арифметику

Tags: javascript, jquery

```
<ul>
<li>45</li>
<li>100</li>
<li>56</li>
<li>23</li>
</ul>
```

надо с помощью js делать вот такую операцию   (45+100+56+23)/4

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
const items = [...document.querySelectorAll('ul > li')];

const sum = items
  .map(item => Number.parseInt(item.textContent, 10))
  .reduce((a, b) => a + b);

const result = sum / items.length;

console.log(result);
```

Пример: http://jsfiddle.net/7a1ed3s9/4/

Comment: Спасибо!.......